# How to pass array data collected in one input field to another using JavaScript without loosing the array property?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$(function() {
    $('#sendit').click(function() {
        var user_id = $('#user_id2').val();
        var all = $('#Senditem').find("input[name='forall[]']").map(function() {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();
        var session = $('#sessionit').val();
        var dateit = Date.now();
        var thisdata = '<span style="color: red">No User Selected';
        var div2 = document.getElementById('resultshere');
        div2.innerHTML = '';

        if (user_id < 1) {
            var div = document.getElementById('resultshere');
            div.innerHTML = thisdata;
        } else {
            var posting =
                $.get(
                    $(this).data('url'), {
                        senddate: dateit,
                        session: $('#sessionit').val(),
                        user_id: $('#user_id2').val(),
                        inputmade: $('#Senditem').find("input[name='forall[]']").map(function() {
                            return $(this).val();
                        }).get()
                    });

            $('#destinationtable tr:first').after('<tr><td>' +
                user_id + all + session + '</td><td> <input name="inputmade" value="' + dateit + 'pim' + user_id + 'pim' + all + 'pim' + session + '">waiting to insert ..</td></tr>'
            );
```

At button click event, the content in input field are collected in an array and pushed to be saved. Then the array content gets append to another table, which will later be accessed and saved again every 5 seconds by another JavaScript below. The issue is, the JavaScript below never get the correct array format.

```
(function autoinsert() {
    var input = $("#destinationtable td:last").find("input").val();

    var req = $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "{{route('AjaxInsertTuckshopIssueAuto')}}",
        data: {
            postthis: input
        },
        error: function() {},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#resultshere').html(data)
            if (input == data) {
                function deleterow(tableID) {
                    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
                    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                    table.deleteRow(rowCount - 1);
                }
                deleterow("destinationtableTable");
            }
        },
        global: false
    });
    setTimeout(autoinsert, 5000);
})();
```

Comment: Are you trying to get an array back from the input? When you put the array into the input it is 'converted' into a string.

Comment: wow. that simple question led me straight to get the solution. thanks Jason Pelletier